# Concrete Mathematics: Not taught how to solve problems.

Tags: soft-question, advice

I've read and studied the first 3 paragraphs from Concrete Mathematics and now I've made the first couple of problems. When I got to the actual homework problems I was lost because I tried to solve the problem the way it was taught to me in the book. After trying to solve it for half a hour I decided to look up the answer.  The solution used a method which wasn't explained in the book.

Take a look, the following problem:

Solve the recurrence"

$$Q_{0} = \alpha; \text{       }  Q_{1} =\beta;$$
$$Q_{n} = (1+Q_{n-1})/ Q_{n-2};  \text{  for  } n>1$$

Additional information:

Assume that: $Q_{n} \neq 0 $ for all $n \geq 0 $ 
Hint:
$$Q_{4}=(1+\alpha)/\beta$$

---

Here is the solution as given by the book:

$$Q_{2} = (1+\beta)/\alpha;Q_{3} = (1+\alpha+\beta)/\alpha\beta;Q_{4}= (1+\alpha)/\beta; Q_{5}= \alpha; Q_{6}=\beta; \text{ So the sequence is periodic! }$$

This is not explained or demonstrated at all in the paragraphs leading up to the problems.

Now my question is: Can I still reap benefits from reading the book without making the exercises? Because I do understand everything in the text, it's just that the problems are screwy..

Kind Regards,

Cro-Magnon

Comment: What lesson have you learnt? SOMETIMES it is useful to investigate small cases.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy I get that but what I don't understand is the periodic sequence part. I mean, the word 'periodic sequence' doesn't even come up in the book until that problem.

Comment: Periodic means it repeats itself.

Comment: Yes... this question teaches you that you shouldn't always look straight to some "method" --- play around with the problem first.

Comment: I will do that then.. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Not all terminology in mathematics books are mathematical. Sometimes you also need a lexicon for the language of the book. =)

Comment: I will push through.. This is painful though :P

Comment: @Cro-Magnon: Look on the bright side. It's far worse if you didn't have solutions. Moreover, there's Math SE to help you if you really can't get what the book says. =)

Comment: @user21820 Yes, Thank you. There is no royal road to mathematics.